# Java programming words

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string, word-frequency

I'm creating a java program which counts the frequency of letters.

My code reads a line of text from a txt file and I'm getting an error, but I don't know the cause.

The error surrounds this code snippet:

```
for (String str : strings)
    if (str.length() < counts.length)
        cou
                    for (String str: strings)
                        if (str.length() < counts.leng
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: 'strings cannot be resolved to a variable'

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are getting an error because 'strings' is not defined. the `for String str : strings` assumes that there is a variable in scope named 'strings' that is a collection or array of strings.

You might also consider using a HashMap rather than an array to track the counts for various lengths. That way you don't have to worry about making sure your array is big enough, etc.

You can also make your code a little simpler by combining your loops:

```
for (String str: strings)
    total += s1.length();
    if (str.length() < counts.length)
        counts[str.length()] += 1;
```

...once you figure out what strings is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

To count the frequency of letters, what you can do is:

```
public static void count_freq(String str)
{
   int []count = new int[256];
   for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
   {
       count[str.charAt(i)]++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Collecting your words into a `HashMap` where the key is the length of the word and the value is the frequency of which the length occurs is a good way to count.

Once you have your `HashMap` built, using Java 8, you can sort the keys from least to greatest and build your output in a `StringBuilder`.

Code Sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String sentence = "I am a great man from a small town";
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    Map<Integer, Integer> wordLengthFrequency = new HashMap();
    for (String word : words) {
        Integer frequency = wordLengthFrequency.get(word.length());
        // Add a new item with a frequency of 1, or increment the frequency count
        wordLengthFrequency.put(word.length(), frequency == null ? 1 : frequency + 1);
    }

    // Iterate through the keys in ascending order to build the output
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    wordLengthFrequency.keySet().stream().sorted().forEach(key -> {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }

        sb.append(wordLengthFrequency.get(key));
    });

    // Display the output
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Results:

```
3, 1, 1, 2, 2
```